# grep line not containing the list of character

Tags: awk, grep

My line can contain alphanumeric or any one of these character `,` , `;` , `/` , `-` ,`_`.
I want to print any line containing characters outside the above listed even though if they have above listed characters

I tried this

```
egrep  '^[[:alnum:]]|\-|\_|\/|\:\,$'
```

It didn't help me

Example :-

```
cat fc
2
a
A
-
_
/
?

egrep -nv '^[[:alnum:]]|\-|\_|\/$' fc
7:?
```

But when I inserted it in the middle of the string:

```
cat fc_v1
hello
hello1
helloA
h@llo
h?llo

egrep -nv '^[[:alnum:]]|\-|\_|\/$' fc_v1
```

but it doesn't work. How can I make it pick up the characters, wherever they appear in the line?

The expectation was to print

h@llo0

h?llo

As they did not have the listed characters

Fortunately i was able to achieve it by

egrep -n '[^_[:alnum:]|-|_|/]' fc_v1

Now the actual requirement does not seem to work with above syntax

cat fc_v2

/a/?hello    -sec=sys,rw, root=c;g,nosuid

/h/hello02      -sec=sys,rw,root=c,nosuid

/h/@hello_      -sec=sys,rw,root=c,nosuid

/h/helloA   -sec=sys,rw,root=c,nosuid

egrep -n '[^_[:alnum:]|/|_|-|\,|\=]' fc_v3

1:/a/?hello    -sec=sys,rw, root=c;g,nosuid

2:/h/hello02      -sec=sys,rw,root=c,nosuid

3:/h/@hello_      -sec=sys,rw,root=c,nosuid

4:/h/helloA   -sec=sys,rw,root=c,nosuid

It prints all the lines, Expected is only line 3 and 1

Comment: Sample input and expected output would be useful. Also, it won't solve your problem but `egrep` is deprecated (use `grep -E`).

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding more details in the comments. When you do that, what is the expected output?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your post. As of now, I am marking it close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @aravindhanSelvan: Please format the code in your post properly. (I tried to, but it's so messy I'm afraid to break something.) Also, your examples don't really help understanding the problem.

Comment: Does it make sense now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you might be looking for:

```
$ grep '[^-[:alnum:]_/:,]' file
h@llo
h?llo
```

but it's a guess since you didn't post expected output for your sample input.

Comment: Thanks Morton , your answer helped me to get to it

Comment: grep  '[^-"#""."[:alnum:][:blank:][:space:]_/:,=-]'

Comment: That makes no sense. THINK about it. blanks ARE spaces and you're listing double quotes and minus signs multiple times in a single character class.